# .trigger('click')

Tags: jquery, load, document, eventtrigger

I am writing a little script to let jquery click a link on page load to open an image with Lightbox, but I can not get it to work. I think it has something to do with my multiple libraries. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('a#gezocht').trigger('click');
            });
    </script>
<!--scriptje-->
<a href="img/bezorgerGezocht.png" rel="lightbox" id="gezocht" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;">Bezorger gezocht!</a>
<!--END scriptje-->
```

Can anyone help me with this? 
Greets,

Jan

Comment: Where's the code that shows the lightbox? We don't need to see what it does, but we definitely need to see how it's hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using instead:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
```

`$(document).ready()` doesn't actually wait until the page is fully loaded. It merely waits until the DOM is loaded and can be manipulated. `$(window).load()` fires at the very end of the page load, when the browser is done.

The only slight catch is that you can't pass in `jQuery` as `$` that way, though you could do the following (though it's rather verbose):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('a#gezocht').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick reply Chris Pratt!
I tried both but neither does work. It just does not load, you can check it out on www.goldenpiehouse.nl